# What is the last line in A Dark Room for iOS?

Tags: ios, a-dark-room

I just spent several hours playing [A Dark Room](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/a-dark-room/id736683061?mt=8). Unfortunately, as I got to the end, I thought there might be sound, so I flipped my iPhone's mute switch off. This caused the iOS volume display to cover up the text on the screen. Before it disappeared, the game was over, and I didn't get a chance to see the last line of text.

What was it?

Spoiler:

> The game has no sound, not even in the last scene.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shivering. Gasping for air. Must find her. The locket glows. Must find her.